# Botframework emulator does not connect

Tags: botframework

After following instructions for "Getting Started" with Bot Builder for Node.js, I am finding that the emulator will not connect. It checks for latest versions and then just sits there.

[image: emulator screenshot]

No error messages from the emulator or the server, which is running locally just fine.

Comment: I've not seen it try to check for updates multiple times. That is a first. Is that is shown the entirety of your log output? I don't see an entry for the attempt to send the "hello" message to the bot.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Does not log the attempt to send.

Comment: It looks as if the emulator never attempted to open its listening port. At the top of the log output, it should have output a line showing the emulator listening port. Are you scrolled up to the top in the screenshot?

Comment: Yes. Never got that initial message.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help here. I shut it down and started it up again and now it is working okay.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Still, that was some strange behavior. I wish I new why it was happening. Cheers.